# How to create DB back from generated scripts?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

[image]

I have created multiple scripts from the above option in SQL Management studio 2012.
In which order should I execute the scripts back to gain the DB?

"Select file per object" - Adding this to help future users searching for this keyword :)

Comment: Are you talking about restoring the DBs from backup files?

Comment: Yes sir. I have generated around 250 .sql files. Now, I need to get DB back from them.

Comment: .sql files are not database backups they are sql code files. See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177429.aspx

Comment: In advanced section, there is an option to select both schema and data to be included in script.

Comment: What's in the ~250 files?

Comment: Please do not create single file for every object it will automatically manage this thing in single file.

Comment: @JayeshGoyani You got me sir. But the data is around 4GB which not managable in single file.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer Those are script files for each DB objects. One <Table>.sql per table etc.

Comment: Scripts that do what? create the tables?  back them up?

Comment: create table and insert data.

Comment: If you only want to take backup of schema then generate script file. If you want to take back backup of schema and data then please create back up file.

Comment: But is it possible to create backup file from remote sql server to local machine?